# Runtime Error 1004 at random when copying images

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have code that copies images from 1 workbook to another. Excel decides to stop the code once in a while with:

> Error 1004 "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed"

Sometimes it successfully copies all images, but most of the time a few are left out (when on error resume next is set). If I choose "Debug" on the error and then press F8, the image is copied. (but `on error resume next` does not have the same effect)

Other ways of copying images, like `.CopyPicture` End result is the same.

```
    'Code below is in a loop

    vArr3 = Split(Cells(1, i).Address(True, False), "$")
    t = vArr3(0)

    Application.Goto Workbooks(BOM).Worksheets("Blad1").Range("a2")
    Workbooks(BOM).Worksheets("Blad1").Shapes.Range(Array("Afbeelding " & im)).Select

    Selection.Copy

    Workbooks(Template).Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Application.Goto Workbooks(Template).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(t & rs)
    Workbooks(Template).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(t & rs).Select

    Workbooks(Template).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(t & rs).PasteSpecial 'Error here

    rs = rs + 5
    im = im + 2
```

I expect Excel to always work 100% correctly. The images (and number of) that are left out is random.

Comment: Probably not your problem but in general, you want to [avoid activate and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code.

Comment: Yes, adding that or removing that does not solve the problem. I'll remove it.

Comment: Try adding `DoEvents` after the Copy line

Comment: @TimWilliams That does seem to make the code work (a lot) better. It copies all the images (but in the back of my mind a voice says that it is just luck that it works now :) ), but sometimes a pasted image has a little cross and the text "image cannot be displayed" in it.

Comment: Yes I've found that `DoEvents` helps but it doesn't fix 100% of issues.  I've not seen the "image cannot be displayed" problem though.

Comment: As expected, after 5 good runs, it fails again.
Also, rarely I also get this warning: The key you specified was not found in the collection.